# Updating The Whole Selected Elastic Record

Tags: elasticsearch, go

Using `olivere/elastic` to connect my Go (1.10) to my Elastic search, which is running in a Docker container.

Now when the database has an update it will run a trigger to my API which should search for that record in my Elastic search, if not found add a new record or if found update the whole record.

Now I have the add new record code in place and its working but I can not see how to update the whole record, selected elements of that record I can but not the whole record.

Here is what I have:

```
testData := []byte(`{"data1":"22222","data2":"ddddd"}`)

script := elastic.NewScript("ctx._source = params.newCont").Params(map[string]interface{}{"newCont": testData})

put1, _ := client.Update().
                Index("myindex").
                Type("mytype").
                Id("id-here").
                Script(script).
                Do(ctx)

fmt.Println( put1 )
```

Now when I update `_source` to something like `_source.data1` I can update that but I want my `testData` var to update all records within this id. The `testData` var is just for testing, I will be loading this from the database, as I have no idea what would have changed, I need the whole record updated?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if it would fix it, but you should try with `testData := map[string]string{"data1": "22222", "data2": "ddddd"}`

Comment: It looks like that does work, for the 1st few of test I have done work, Many Thanks. I would have never thought about making it a map

Comment: My understanding is that `_source` cannot be a string, but has to be an object. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read the unit tests of [github.com/olivere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) as well. E.g. [update_test.go](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/update_test.go) and [update_integration_test.go](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/update_integration_test.go) illustrate how to do updates. Combine that the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update.html) and you will become a pro with Elasticsearch very soon :-)